# Correct way to call a database into a view

Tags: php, model-view-controller, pdo

I am trying to display the database on the `database.phtml` page of my website. This page is a view.

So far I have a model called DatabaseConect.php

```
<?php

abstract class DatabaseConect {

protected $db = NULL;

public function __construct (PDO $db) {
    $this->db = $db;
}
}

class Database extends DatabaseConect {

public $props = array ();

private function getPage ($id) {
    $q = $this->db->prepare('SELECT * FROM retrofootball_products');
    $ret = $res->fetchAll();
    return ($this->props=$ret);
}

}

$db = new PDO('mysql:host=helios.csesalford.com;dbname=pd12', 'helloworld', 'password'); //I have changed the log in details
```

Then in my view

```
<?php require('template/header.phtml') ?>

<?php 
$page = new Database ($db);
?>

<?php require('template/footer.phtml') ?>
```

I have been trying to find stuff on Stackoverflow and Have come across these articles but they are little above my head as I am new to this:

[Properly calling the database from Model in an MVC application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5895805/properly-calling-the-database-from-model-in-an-mvc-application)
http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/178831/using-pdo-with-mvc

My question is what is the best way using MVC to connect to a database and then display this in the view? Do I need to use `PDO::FETCH`in the model to display the results into a variable and then call this variable in the view?

EDIT: Like suggest I have used a bootstrap in a controller. Do i need to create a new instance of this in my view for it to work? Also where am i running the query in the correct place?

```
<?php

class Dependency_Manager {

private $db;

public function __construct($settings) {
    $this->db = new PDO('mysql:host=helios.csesalford.com;dbname=helloworld', 'password',   'php54');
}

public function getDB() {
    return $db;
    }
}

class CMS {
public function __construct(PDO $db) {
    //$stmt = $db->query('SELECT * FROM retrofootball_products');
    }
}

$settings = array();

$dm = new Dependency_Manager($settings);
$cms = new CMS($dm->getDB());
```

Comment: Why don't you establish a database connection from your controller? (index.php?)

Comment: I thought you shouldn't have SQL in controllers?

Comment: It's doesn't matter really, just connect to MySQL in a bootstrapper

Comment: Can you show/give me an example of this.

Comment: @JoshuaHornby .... When using a MVC framework. The database is always called from the Model. The controller should tie the correct model method to the correct view only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> <sub>**FYI:** view is not a template. In properly implemented MVC, views are instances (as in - objects made from classes) that are responsible for all of the UI logic. To achieve it, they often juggle multiple templates.</sub>

The confusing part about DB connection *(and interaction with any other form of storage)* is that it is required only at very low-level structures - [data mappers](http://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/dataMapper.html) <sup>[**book chapter**](http://books.google.lv/books?id=vqTfNFDzzdIC&lpg=PP1&pg=PT213#v=onepage&q&f=false)</sup>.

The connection itself should be provided to each data mapper *(that requires it, because not all mapper would work with SQL database)* instance through  factory. Code example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12739161/727208) - the relevant part is the `StructureFactory` class definition.

The factory for creating data mappers would injected in an instance, which need to use the mappers. Otherwise would be violating [LoD](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?LawOfDemeter).

The view should not have any idea about the origin of data. It would only request some information from model layer.

> <sub>**P.S.:** [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5906211/727208) ancient answer is quite outdated. It contains my understanding of MVC more then 18 month ago. I soon will get an update. You will find [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5864000/727208) to be much more up-to-date.</sub>